# Linux Distribution with Good KDE Integration

Tags: linux, kde

I need linux distribution with following packages/features:

- Any **popular** web browser (Fireox, Opera or Chrome) with KDE intergation
- Any office package (OpenOffice, LibreOffice, etc.) with KDE integration
- Rolling release (optional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [OpenSuse](http://www.opensuse.org/en/) with [Tubmleweed](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed)?

Comment: Or how about 64 Studio, or aptosid, or Astra Linux, or Bharat Operating System Solutions, or Canaima, or Caixa Mágica, or Corel Linux, or CrunchBang Linux, or Dreamlinux, or Elive, or Emdebian Grip, or Finnix, or gNewSense, or grml, or HandyLinux, or Instant, or ebKiosk, or Kali Linux, or Kanotix, or Knoppix, or Kurumin, or LEAF Project, or LiMux, or LinuxBBQ, or Linux, or int Debian Edition, or Maemo, or MEPIS, or MintPPC, or Musix GNU+Linux, or NepaLinux, or OpenZaurus, or Pardus, or Parsix, or PureOS, or Rxart, or Sacix, or Siduction, or Skolelinux, or SolusOS, or SolydXK, or... or... :)